# VBA ActiveX control changes size after sharing

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a simple excel form with an ActiveX control (ListBox)

When I share this over email, the recipient does the following steps:
1. Open the excel
2. Enable Content for the macro

Now - the ListBox grows in size.

I'm unable to dynamically resize or figure out the exact event for "Enable Content".

Is there anyway I can retain the dimensions of the ListBox?

Comment: On close, you could save the dimension in a hidden sheet / cell, then on open, resize?

Comment: "sharing" is confusing here. Please clarify/confirm that we're not talking about a *shared workbook* (which are famously broken in all kinds of ways).

Comment: @Mat'sMug I meant attaching as an email attachment over outlook.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn That would still need a macro, which means that code should trigger right after "Enable Content" is clicked. I'm not able to figure out the event for this.

Comment: @JKarthik "on open" would be the `Workbook_Open` event handler, in `ThisWorkbook`. Can you tell us what the property values are for the listbox control? Is it configured to "move and size with cells"?

Comment: FWIW I can't repro in Excel 2010 (64-bit).

Comment: @Mat'sMug It's Move and Don't Size With Cells

Comment: So currently the user must go to Trust Center to Enable Content? Maybe you could have a 'main form' that set's the size as required. I simply tested resizing an ActiveX control (for an Image).

Comment: @Mat'sMug you're suggestion for Workbook_Open helped. Move it to answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with sharing the document via email. It has everything to do with window scaling. To prove this to yourself try connecting to a projector with the the excel document open. Use some Active X controls and they will shrink or Expand. I've had this problem and found the only way to avoid it in a reasonable manor is to implant a form inside the excel document that holds all the needed controls or ensure the end user is not scaling their display in any manor.

Comment: I had the same problem during presentations and it is infuriating. I have better luck with `MSForms` controls instead of `ActiveX` at the price of lesser functionality.